# How effect the column structure alteration to the related SSIS Package?

Tags: ssis, alter-table

I have a SSIS package to transfer data from one table to another table. When i change one table structure - increase the length of one column - after that i run the SSIS package it get error.But run after edit and save(with out making any change) the package then it success.

Is it necessary to edit SSIS package when we alter column data length?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, external metadata refresh happening. So to populate those changes across the packages you need to edit and save.